# filter by last modified is not working copying files from azure blob

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have setup a copy pipeline, which is working fine.
Now I have tried to add a filter with last modified, but it is not working.

my filter
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIDgf.png)

a sample file it should detect
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eC9QI.png)

it doesn't detect any files
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qp4EP.png)

this is the pipeline without the filter
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uHt5.png)

Comment: Did you make sure the Last Modified timestamp is in UTC?

Comment: you can see the screenshots. I'm using the gui to setup the time. So I'm assuming it is translating. I have also tried in the fomat @adddays(utcnow(),-6) to @adddays(utcnow(),-5)

Answer (score 0):

I got similar kind issue with last modified filter using copy activity.

- Make sure your date is of type UTC as like below, if not convert it into UTC like below :
- The above will only read the files if they are in that time period of UTC.

Add this dynamic content filter by modified as per your required date.

```
@convertToUtc('01/10/23', 'Pacific Standard Time')
```

[image]

**Try this alterative approach using get metadata.Follow this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74531579/data-factory-synapse-copy-task-fails-with-staging-enabled-when-no-files-found/74545887#74545887) thread by Rakesh Govindula .**

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use Azure Dynamic Functions like Addmintues so if your file was written two minutes ago it can detect by searching in Minutes and adding utcnow and -2 represent last two minutes. You can also add Days and Hours as well.

Let me know if this help otherwise same can be done with Get metadata Activity in azure

[image]